# Retrieve data from DataBase and Fill a List

Tags: .net, wpf, database, list, datatable

```
public List<Item> ListItemCollection;  

String connString = "SERVER=;" +
          "DATABASE=;" +
          "UID=;" +
          "PASSWORD=;"; 


private void GetItems()
{

String query = @"myQuery";
DataTable theTable = new DataTable();

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            {

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);

                da.Fill(theTable); // here all works fine.

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                {
                             /// At this point throws the exception .....

                    // Loop through each record.
                    while (reader.Read())  
                    {
                        ListItemCollection.Add(new Item());
                    }
                }

            }
}

theTable.Columns.Clear();
theTable.Rows.Clear();
theTable.Clear();

ListItemCollection.Items.Clear();
DataContext = ListItemCollection;
ListItemCollection.Items.Refresh();
```

inner exception .. {"Connection must be valid and open."}

If I use a DataAdapter and fill a dataTable "da.Fill(theTable)" things work pretty smooth, maybe there is a way to transfer data from DataTable to List?  theTable.Columns.List?

The final purpose of all this, is that I want to add grouping to a ListControl (ListBox, DataGrid, ListView), setting DataContext code-behind &  Binding ItemSource in XAML. Perhaps you can group the list of the datatable?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to open your MySqlConnection at some point:

```
conn.Open();
```

Suggest right before your `ExecuteReader();`

This will ensure you don't get the `Connection must be valid and open` exception.

Comment: My suspicion (lo these many years later as I try to canonicalize a potential dupe) is that this was a case of DataAdapter opening and closing a connection and a subsequent conn.Open() getting into an unsupported state in the MySqlDbConnection code - but I don't have a MySql stack to test on. Self-answering this question could be useful to anyone else in this pickle, though....

Answer (score 0):

why not bind directly to the datatable you are filling? it looks like you are doing this in codebehind too. Working with the xaml would be a lot cleaner...

the reason you can fill the datatable and then get an error on the reader is that the datadapter can manage its own connection whereas the datareader needs a explicit reference to the connection object.

btw. You are hitting the database twice this way.

Comment: well, thanks I just wanted to give a little more info about the fill table. Anyway, I need to group the datagrid itemsource, and for that, I need to fill a List. Is there a way to accomplish grouping without any ListCollection?. Actually I am just setting the DataContext = theTable.

Comment: I believe if you bind your table to a collectionview in xaml, then bind your datagrid to that you are able to then group...I have only used a datagrid once so far, and it took alot of setup to get it to work the way I wanted. The grouping in this scenario would actually be through the collectionview

Answer (score 0):

I added a CollectionViewSource with a groupDescription, getdefaultview of my control itemsource.

myView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItemsControl.ItemsSource);
       PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("order");
       myView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

found the example here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2009/07/16/wpf-xaml-listboxes-with-a-grouping-capability.aspx